# Two sides of quadrilateral $ABCD$ intersect at $E$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles, angle

Quadrilateral $ABCD$ is inscribed in a circle. The extensions of $AD$ and $BC$ intersect at $E$, such that $D$ is between $A$ and $E$. If $BC=2DE,AD:EC=7:2$ and $\cos\measuredangle AEB=\dfrac78$, find $\cos\measuredangle ABC$.

[image]

Since $\measuredangle ABC+\measuredangle ADC=180^\circ,$ angle $\measuredangle CDE$ is also equal to $\beta$. Triangles $ABE$ and $CDE$ also share $\measuredangle E$. By AA Similarity, $\triangle ABE\sim\triangle CDE$ with a ratio of $\dfrac{AB}{CD}=\dfrac{BE}{DE}=\dfrac{AE}{CE}$.

$Let DE=x, BC=2x$ and $AD=7y, EC=2y$. We have to find $$\cos\beta=\dfrac{AB^2+BE^2-AE^2}{2\cdot AB\cdot BE}$$ and we have $$\cos\varphi=\dfrac{ED^2+EC^2-CD^2}{2\cdot ED\cdot EC}=\dfrac{x^2+4y^2-CD^2}{2\cdot x\cdot 2y}=\dfrac{x^2+4y^2-CD^2}{4xy}$$ I don't see how to relate $AB$ and $CD$ (other than the similar triangles) Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

From the similarity of $\triangle ABE$ and $\triangle CDE$ we have
$$\frac{x}{2y} = \frac{2x+2y}{x+7y}$$
$$x^2+7xy = 4xy + 4y^2 $$
$$(x+4y)(x-y) = 0$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you! This means $x=y$, but I still don't see how to calculate $\cos\measuredangle\beta$. The segment $AB$ is also in the formula for $\cos\measuredangle ABE$ for triangle $ABE$.

Comment: Actually I have an idea. By the law of sines in triangle $ABE$ $$AB=2x\sqrt{6}$$ Then using the similarity $CD=\dfrac{x\sqrt6}{2}$. Now substituting in $$\cos\beta=\dfrac{AB^2+BE^2-AE^2}{2\cdot AB\cdot BE}=...=-\dfrac{\sqrt6}4$$

Comment: We don’t even need $CD$ (in terms of $x$, of course). Anyway, is this the right answer? Did you get it too? Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Medi You got the correct answer. And you are right, to solve the problem we don't need to know the length of $CD$. Anyway, now we know that it is $\frac14 AB$.